How to find tr with multiple td contains particular text with beautifulsoup?
I need to find the <tr> data where multiple <td> contains particular text (10.13.18.150, StreaNetwork)
<tr id="fr119" onclick="fr_toggle(119)" ondblclick="document.location='firewall_rules_edit.php?id=120';" class="ui-sortable-handle" style="">
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" id="frc119" onclick="fr_toggle(119)" name="rule[]" value="120">
</td>

    <td title="traffic is passed">
    <a href="?if=lan&amp;act=toggle&amp;id=120" usepost="">
        <i class="fa fa-check text-success" title="click to toggle enabled/disabled status"></i>
    </a>
    <i class="fa fa-cog" title="advanced setting: gateway PeakJioAirtel " style="cursor: pointer;"></i>                     
    </td>
    <td> 
    10.13.18.150                                                    
    </td>
    <td> 
    StreaNetwork                                                
    </td>
</tr>

My Code:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
complete_soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, 'html.parser')
complete_soup.find('tr:has(td:contains("StreaNetwork"))')

Is there any solution for this problem?

If it were me, I'd just grab all of the <tr> rows, and then iterate through them looking for where the 3rd and 4th <td> have my data.

@So I need to iterate all tr and need to check for my condition.. Is there any solution with td contains text and find parent tr

Try to adjust your find() to select() to use the css selectors and your script will grab the <tr>.
In addition iterate the Resultset and print :nth-child(3), if the content is still in this element:
complete_soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, 'html.parser')
for e in complete_soup.select('tr:has(td:contains("StreaNetwork"))'):
    print(e.select_one(':nth-child(3)').get_text(strip=True))

or check against the ip:
complete_soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, 'html.parser')
for e in complete_soup.select('tr:has(td:contains("StreaNetwork"))'):
    ip = e.select_one(':nth-child(3)').get_text(' ',strip=True)
    if '10.13.18.150' in ip:
        print(ip)


@Thanks for support


Find all tr instead of checking it contains StreaNetwork TD
Run a loop of all TR and get all TD tags
Run a Loop of all TD and and get text of it to check it contains string


Thanks.. Is there any solution with td contains both text and find parent tr (Is this possible).

Yes you can find specific text using 'StreaNetwork' in td.get_text() and find a parent TR using td.find_parent('tr')

I need to check both text..Is it possible (10.13.18.150, StreaNetwork).

Yes you can achieve it using AND while checking in TD text.  if '10.13.18.150' in td.get_text() and 'StreaNetwork' in td.get_text()
